# Rails] Images erased after a new commit on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, carrierwave

I'm using Carrierwave to upload images, and my app is on Heroku right now.
Images are uploaded successfully unless I push a new commit to heroku. Images that I uploaded before a push seem to be erased when a new commit comes in. Does anyone know the reason behind and how to fix this issue?

**Update:**
The problem becomes, *using carrierwave on Heroku without a storage server like Amazon EC3*. Heroku does not save files in public folder, where carrierwave uploads by default.

**app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:**

```
  def store_dir
   "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

And you need to change this to somewhere in the tmp folder in order to preserve your image files after each commit. I tried to change it to

```
"#{Rails.root}/tmp/uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
```

But it does not work. I checked on my local environment, and the image is stored in the right location successfully. So I guess if I just set the routes to the right location, this could work. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Where are your uploaded images going? Into your database? The Heroku file system? Somewhere else?

Comment: @muistooshort, it goes to public/uploads/<model>/image/<model_id>/<file_name> http://myapp.com/uploads/post/image/4/imagename.png

Comment: I take it that you don't know that [Heroku has a (sort of) read-only file system](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem) so anything you write to the file system will go away. You'll need to store your uploaded images elsewhere.

Comment: @muistooshort yes, you are correct. Could you check my update?

Comment: I meant elsewhere as in outside the file system. You need to go the EC3 route or something similar.

Comment: @muistooshort did you mean AWS S3?

Comment: @rubish: Yes, I'm pretty sure I mean S3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Heroku does not allow storing static files (unless it's associated the application itself), you should make `Carrierwave` upload to a remote repository (e.g. Amazon S3) using `fog`. Everytime a user uploads a file, the file will be automatically uploaded to your S3 storage instead of Heroku.